# Can't adjust brightness or contrast on Canon n650u scanner running simple-scan & 17.04

Tags: drivers, brightness, canon, scanner

I have a Canon N650U scanner that scans quite happily with simple-scan 3.20.0. However, the scans are too light and washed out. Adjusting the brightness and contrast sliders in preferences have no effect.

I did a little digging on the SANE website and noticed that there's no backend listed for this scanner. I've also noticed that the scans under xsane are washed out as well. This kind of leads me to believe that this might be a SANE issue.

I had an HP 4C SCSI scanner that worked very well and I could adjust brightness and contrast to my heart's content. Unfortunately, a thunderstorm cooked the power supply and replacements seem to be made from unobtainium, leaving me with the Canon.

Any help would be appreciated.

All the best,

Bill

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Go to /etc/sane.d and edit plustek.conf. Go to the gamma options and change them all to 0.4 (that's the number that worked for me).

Why won't the brightness and contrast sliders work in simple scan? I dunno. Could be a bug. But this is a good workaround. Now I can scan my various and sundry body parts and email them to elected officials all over the world. I am so happy.

Comment: some would install xsane as the front-end as you can tweak many values from it `sudo apt install xsane`

Comment: Does that mean your scanner is identified, not as one of the scanners listed in the canon_xx.conf files, but as a scanner of `plustek.conf` file?  ie: a "LM9831/2/3 based USB scanner".